# Gradient mask on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, gradient

I have a UIView and want to have the bottom part of it fade out to 0 opacity.

May this be done to a UIView (CALayer) in order to affect an entire UIView and its content?

Comment: For others that struggle with gradient mask, it will not work if applied to a `UIStackView`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by setting [`CAGradientLayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) as your view's layer mask:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

...

CAGradientLayer *maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

maskLayer.frame = view.bounds;
maskLayer.colors = @[(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
maskLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);
maskLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);

view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

*P.S. You also need to link `QuartzCore.framework` to your app to make things work.*

Comment: I know this is older, but what's the deal with getting cgcolor's and then bridging them back to pointers? The `colors` property says it is an array of UIColors.

Comment: abstract from docs - **colors** - An array of CGColorRef objects defining the color of each gradient stop. To store them in NSArray we cast them to id. Frankly, I thought we need bridged cast when using ARC, but the code compiled fine as it is now

Answer (score 1):

## Using an Image as the mask to prevent Layout issues.

Although Vladimir's answer is correct, the issue is to sync the gradient layer after view changes. For example when you rotate the phone or resizing the view. So instead of a layer, you can use an image for that:

```
@IBDesignable
class MaskableLabel: UILabel {
    var maskImageView = UIImageView()

    @IBInspectable
    var maskImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            maskImageView.image = maskImage
            updateView()
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateView()
    }

    func updateView() {
        if maskImageView.image != nil {
            maskImageView.frame = bounds
            mask = maskImageView
        }
    }
}
```

Then with a simple gradient mask [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhIJH.png), You can see it even right in the storyboard.

[image: Preview]

## Note:

You can use this `class` and replace `UILabel` with any other view you like to subclass.

## Bones:

You can use any other shaped image as the mask just like that.