Swift: Gradient from blur to transparent
I have a view with a blur effect, and as a subview, I have a scrollview. I would like to add a fading effect at the top and bottom.
The fading effect should go from blur to transparent and should be a continuation of the background.
I don’t know how to approach this at all; here’s a picture of my result and the expected result.
At the right its the expected result

I stated with the simple code:
let topGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
let bottomGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

topGradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8).cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
topGradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
contentView.layer.addSublayer(topGradientLayer)
        
bottomGradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8).cgColor]
bottomGradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
contentView.layer.addSublayer(bottomGradientLayer)


I don't see really the gradient of color on the right. I see more a Gradient Mask on the text. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506852/gradient-mask-on-uiview

You need to use blurred component (NSVisualEffectView/UIVisualEffectView) and to use opacity mask over it with black-to-white gradient.

Basic way is create a gradient mask image in any photo editor (gradient must start from bottom to top) then by imageview mask it to your component (label, textview).With this way you will avoid layout issues with layer also
